# How to setup my unpartitioned, unmounted SSD?

Tags: linux, centos, command-line

I am running a CentOS 7 server with a 500gb SSD. Via SSH i got this output

```
[root@localhost ~]# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1       33538048 33537160       888 100% /
devtmpfs        16316684        0  16316684   0% /dev
tmpfs           16330724        0  16330724   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           16330724    10616  16320108   1% /run
tmpfs           16330724        0  16330724   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            3266148        0   3266148   0% /run/user/0
```

Not much space left. Using lsblk command i get

```
[root@localhost ~]# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 447.1G  0 disk
sdb      8:16   0    50G  0 disk
├─sdb1   8:17   0    32G  0 part /
└─sdb2   8:18   0    18G  0 part [SWAP]
```

How can i use the device "sda"? I would assume i need to make a partition and then mount it, but i am not sure how to do that

Comment: Please be more specific about what you mean by "use the device 'sda'". Do you want `sda` to contain your entire root filesystem (`/`), or do you want to combine `sdb1` with a partition on `sda` such as they appear as a single partition? Do you have reliable backups of `sdb1`?

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
parted /dev/sda mklabel gpt mkpart P1 ext4 0% 100%
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1
mkdir /media/ssd
mount /dev/sda1 /media/ssd
```

depending on what you want to do with it there are other options (lvmcache, btrfs, etc)

Comment: You forgot creating an fstab entry

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro That was intentional as we have no idea wat the OP wants to "use" it for.

Answer (score -1):

```
mount /dev/sda /mnt
```

will mount the device 'sda' in the 'dev' directory which contains device files into the mnt directory which is a suitable mount point for devices. if it says permission denied or something add 'sudo' infront of the command above.

Comment: I would advise improving the question. It is missing essential steps, as verifying it the disk has something, partitioning, formating, creating a file system, inserting a line info fstab and formatting it.